# Assign left/right tag to nodes in the binary-tree

Tags: binary-tree

I have a binary (undirected) tree.
I want to assign to each (child) node a left/right tag.

How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: What language are you working in?  What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in C by making the tree structure as

```
struct tree { 
    char tag[4];
    struct tree * left;
    struct tree *right;
};
```